# Restore Purchase - RevenueCat webHook

Tags: ios, revenuecat

So we get rid of all AppStore/PlayStore integration for processing payment and rely fully on RevenueCat webHook.

the main issue that we encounter so far is that when we have a restoreSubscription the RevenueCat webHook does't react also if user has a purchase already and he receive "You are currently subscribed to this" and press OK again the RevenueCat webHook does't react.

How can we manage this 2 scenarios ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a webhook from RevenueCat if the customer is already subscribed and restores subscriptions. Since they've already subscribed, you should already have received the purchase webhook for the customer. If you need to know when one of your customers taps the Restore button you can trigger the event from within your app.

Comment: got it, so basically if we miss a hook, or revenueCat fails to deliver a hook that informs the server that user purchased something we should handle this situations

Comment: Yes restoreTransactions() is a device side sync. If you need to re-sync status server-side you can make a request to `GET /subscribers` to retrieve the current subscription status